# threaded=True not working on Flask server

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, server

I have an Apache server running Flask. The Flask application in called more than a thousand times per minute, which causes delays because it is run single-threaded.

I have seen that adding "threaded=True" like this is supposed to help:

```
app.run(threaded=True)
```

But it is not helping. Is there a particular other server setting that needs to be changed to allow Flask to run multiple operations as once, rather having to wait for each page to finish before it can start on the next one?

Comment: How do you run your app? Do you have some proper handler of your application, like uWSGI (there is `mod_uwsgi` plugin for that in Apache2)? If so, enable `threads` in uWSGI because by default it runs single-threaded and discards Flask's settings.. If not, this might be of help: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html#compiletime , as you may need to configure threading in your Apache similarly.